# Number of transactions in Ledger

Tags: ledger, protocol

Does one ledger hold multiple transactions from different accounts?
By looking at the single ledger, I see only a [few transactions](https://stellarchain.io/ledger/17057632). In the above ledger sequence, there are only 2 transactions.I assume the ledger can hold more transactions.

As a DAPP developer (token creator, contract creator etc), do I need to worry about ledger feature such as entry, sequence? I view ledgers as a single database where individual ledger are chained.

Comment: what do you mean by entry sequence here? Do you mean sequence number of transactions? Do you mean the sequence in which transactions are submitted to the ledger or like the sequence in which operations are chained to create a transaction?

Also, the word DAPP doesn't apply to Stellar Developers, because the mechanics are quite different as compared to an ethereum DAPP developer.

Comment: 1. I meant ledger sequence number.
2. yeah, I mean app based on Stellar network, like a payment app etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ledger may contain up to **50 transactions** (parameter `max_tx_set_size` in [ledger details](https://horizon.stellar.org/ledgers/?order=desc&limit=1)). This value is not a constant, it is determined by the current protocol version, and may be changed by validators voting in the nearest future. Each transaction may contain up to **100 operations**.

You don't need to worry about ledger sequence, operation identifiers, etc.  They are generated automatically by Stellar Core validators. Stellar gives you an abstraction layer that hides insignificant details.

The only important parameter is an **account sequence**. A transaction always contain `source_account` and `source_account_sequence` parameters. If current account sequence doesn't match the parameter specified in transaction, it will fail. That's why Horizon doesn't allow you to submit more than one transaction in each ledger (the API call result is not returned until the ledger is closed). Once the transaction is applied, account sequence is incremented.

It is highly recommended to load up-to-date account details before building a transaction. More details [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/transactions.html).